# Dynamic casting a ** array in c++

Tags: c++, downcast

I'm trying to make a function that reads a polymorphic dynamic array and prints a different thing for each class. The code is something like this:

```
class A {};
class B: public A {};
class C: public A {};

void function (const A &a) {
    if(B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)){
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    if(C *c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a)){
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
}

int main () {
    A **array = new A* [2];
    array [0] = new B;
    array [1] = new C;

    function (array [0]); // To print B
    function (array [1]); // To print C
}
```

But it gives me an error that says:

```
cannot dynamic_cast ‘a’ (of type ‘const class A’) to type ‘class B*’ (source is not a pointer)
```

What can I do?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` doesn't work unless `A` contains at least one virtual function. And when adding virtual functions, why not have one doing the display and skip the cast?

Comment: I'll need it for other functions, in fact what I did is overcharging the << function for each, A, B and C

Answer (score 3):

Apply a dynamic cast to the address of `a`, e.g. `dynamic_cast<const B*>(&a)`. While it's true that a reference is a pointer under the hood (sort of), you can't just treat it as a pointer.

However, I would advise against writing something like this, which doesn't scale.

PS - As commenters suggest, you need to dynamic-cast to a const pointer, while your example casts to a non-const.

Comment: cannot dynamic_cast ‘& a’ (of type ‘const class A*’) to type ‘class B*’ (conversion casts away constness)

Comment: @RamonPozo: Yeah, sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @RamonPozo: Then add your new attempt to the question and list the error you got.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, *why not skip the cast?* Moreover, if you want your derived classes to exhibit different behavior, why not explicitly define that different behavior? That is, using `dynamic_cast<>` says something about your intent—as does the alternative.

That being said, as others have also stated, your base class should have at least one `virtual` function and your derived classes should be publicly derived.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void operator()() {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }

    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void operator()() override {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }

    void print() override  {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void operator()() override {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }

    void print() override {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> v;
    auto pa = new A{};
    auto pb = new B{};
    auto pc = new C{};

    v.push_back(pa);
    v.push_back(pb);
    v.push_back(pc);

    for(auto& elem : v)
        elem->print();

    delete pa;
    delete pb;
    delete pc;

    return 0;
}
```

I think this is part of the answer to your question. I believe another portion of your question can be answered with:

```
std::vector<A> vv;
A a;
B b;
C c;

a(); // A
b(); // B
c(); // C

vv.push_back(a);
vv.push_back(b);
vv.push_back(c);

for(auto& elem : vv)
    elem(); // ?
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed up your code so it would work the way you want.  But I suggest you do not do this:  using `new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]` and raw pointers are not best practice.  Using `dynamic_cast` is a very bad code smell.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

namespace
{

class A
{
public:
  virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B: public A
{
};

class C: public A
{
};

void function (A const& a)
{
  if (B const* b = dynamic_cast<B const*>(&a))
  {
    cout << "B" << endl;
  }

  if (C const* c = dynamic_cast<C const*>(&a))
  {
    cout << "C" << endl;
  }
}

} // anonymous namespace

int main ()
{
  A* array[2] =
  {
    new B,
    new C
  };

  function(*array[0]); // To print B
  function(*array[1]); // To print C
}
```